# Installing Mac OS X Mountain lion Apple iD Error

Tags: mac, error

[image]

Can someone please help me with this Issue? Im trying to install mountain lion and i always get this error! My Mac Is a 2007 iMac, kind of second hand, 320.07 GB WDC Hard drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the Apple ID that you signed in with has no record of purchasing Mountain Lion. If you purchased Mountain Lion, use the Apple ID that you used to purchase it.

Alternatively, install Mavericks as it's free.

Comment: Ok im going to install Mavericks but im typing right now from Safari in recovery mode, if im going to install, how? I erased the hard drive. I have no other computer. :l

Comment: My mom called apple and they said to go to a apple store near you and i live in Queens, NY what would be the nearest store? Also Mountain Lion is around 30 bucks, is it worth it? Is there any download or anything?

Comment: @JackTheGamer Use Internet Recovery (boot with ⌘⌥R) which will download the original installer. Install OS X using that.

Comment: Is that Command+R or Command+Option+R?

Comment: I got they key but i have one problem, my Mac wouldn't boot into internet recovery :(

Comment: @JackTheGamer Command+Option+R.

Comment: GRGAR, my Mac is a 2007 Mid.