# OS X Not Booting into Internet Recovery

Tags: imac, internet-recovery

I own a **iMac 2007 (Mid)**.

I've realised that whenever i try to boot onto internet recovery, it doesn't. It boots onto OS X Utilities. I wiped my drive to re-install OS X but i currently don't have a install disc. I'll be getting a install disc in 1 month because the shipping got delayed due to the weather.

I want to use a faster way to somehow install OS X on my iMac. I thought of using Internet Recovery but it doesn't boot into Internet Recovery. I can't wait 1 month. Does my iMac not support Internet Recovery or it's just not working? It can't  be the key's because i have 2 apple keyboard's and tested the keys.

Can anyone help me out?

---

This question also relates to the problem : [Installing Mac OS X Mountain lion Apple iD Error](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/117091/installing-mac-os-x-mountain-lion-apple-id-error)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your iMac : 2007 (mid) doesn't support Internet Recovery. You can wait 1 month or use the faster way = Head to a Apple Store near you.

Well if there's no apple store near you, I think you should use a friend's computer to create a bootable OS X Install USB flash drive.

The steps to install OS X using a USB are here : http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/apple-in-the-enterprise/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-to-install-os-x/